# Python Logarithm Function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, logarithm

I'm looking for an example of operations with logarithms in Python. I've tried with `sympy` and `numpy` and I still can't do what I want. For example, for an input like this:

```
log(x+1)+log(4-x)=log(100) # it's just an example
```

the output should give me the `x` value. I need to do this with any other functions like `log(x+1)=4` or `log(x)-log(x+1)=log(x)`.

Is there some method or somewhere (documentation or similar) where can I find how to do this?

Comment: It would take less time to solve by hand than in Python. Or at least easier to simplify a lot before handing it to Python.

Comment: Do you mean you want to automatically *solve* the equation you define? Have you read [this](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html)?

Comment: Only do it programmatically if you can't do it mathematically. What is your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here?

Comment: log and exponentiation are inverse functions. When you have something like `log(x+1)+log(4-x)=log(100)` you can solve this analytically by usage of the log laws. `log(x+1) + log(x-4) = log((x+1)*(x-4))` then `log((x+1)*(x-4)) = log(100) => (x+1)*(x-4) = 100` which is just a quadratic which is straightforward to solve. Make sure you can't just use a simplifying mathematical transformation to your problem before you start using heavy-weight numerical solutions techniques.

Comment: @cdhagmann no it wouldn't.

Comment: I'm unclear why there are close votes for this question. The commenters seem to think that you should avoid using computers to do things that you can do by hand, so please respond by snail mail.

Comment: @asmeurer no, the commenters think you should use the correct tool for the job - it's not clear computers are the correct tool here (at least given the poor question description)

Comment: Maybe it would seem that way if you are unfamiliar with computer algebra systems. But the answers should make it clear that computers are a great tool for this job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you need to do because you said you tried sympy already.  However, it looks like you just want to solve for x in an algebraic equation.

Solving for x in the equation

```
log(x+1)+log(4-x)=log(100)
```

using sympy would be

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol, solve, log
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(log(x+1) + log(4-x) - log(100), x)
[3/2 - 5*sqrt(15)*I/2, 3/2 + 5*sqrt(15)*I/2]
```

If you want, you can check that these two solutions are correct with numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = 3/2 - 5*np.sqrt(15)*1j/2
>>> b = 3/2 + 5*np.sqrt(15)*1j/2
>>> np.log(a + 1) + np.log(4-a)
(4.6051701859880918+0j)
>>> np.log(b + 1) + np.log(4-b)
(4.6051701859880918+0j)
>>> np.log(100)
4.6051701859880918
```

Is that not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Since `log` is a non-linear function, you will need to use a non-linear solver like `scipy.optimize.fsolve`. It take in a function and a guess value and returns the answer in the form of an array. For simplicity reason, I defined the function as a `lambda` function since we don't need it outside of this line, but creating a function using standard `def` methods would work as well. The `[0]` on the back end get the value out of the array to return just the float.

```
import scipy.optimize
import math

scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x: math.log(x+1) - 4, 5)[0] # 5 is guess value
>>> 53.598
# Check
math.exp(4) - 1
>>> 53.598
```

Comment: Provide more commentary on what you are doing.  This will simply promote copying and pasting without understanding.

Comment: @rayryeng, based on the question, that is all they want anyway. But I am in the process of editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Good advice already given. I just note that you can also check the answer in SymPy.

```
>>> L, R = log(x+1)+log(4-x), log(100)
>>> eq = Eq(L, R)
>>> eq
log(-x + 4) + log(x + 1) == log(100)
>>> sol = solve(eq)
>>> [eq.subs(x, i) for i in sol]
[True, True]
```

So in the Eq form the solutions were verified automatically. This is not always
true but you can use numerical evaluation to check the value:

```
>>> f = eq.lhs - eq.rhs; f
log(-x + 4) + log(x + 1) - log(100)
>>> f.subs(x, sol[0])
-log(100) + log(5/2 - 5*sqrt(15)*I/2) + log(5/2 + 5*sqrt(15)*I/2)
>>> _.n()
0.e-124 + 0.e-125*I
>>> f.subs(x, sol[0]).n(chop=True)  # the small numbers can be chopped
0
```